# Expanded life-span of variables through std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

With the C++11 `unique_ptr`, an object's lifespan seems to be extended outside of its usual scope like in the following (rather contrived) example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<char> uPtr(nullptr);
    {
        char c = 'X';
        cout << "c = " << c << endl;
        uPtr.reset(&c);
        c = 'Y';
    }
    cout << "c = " << *uPtr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
`c = X`
`c = Y`

The character c, which would usually be released at the end of the scope, survives until the end of the program. The second output is 'Y', showing that the `unique_ptr` does not simply copy its value.

Is it recommended to extend the lifespan of a variable in an way?
Is this safe, or does it carry the same dangers as a reference?

Comment: *"an object's lifespan can be extended outside of its usual scope"* -- No, it can't.  Your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: Remember, the worst symptom of undefined behavior is your program acting like it does what you want. Always question a working program...;)

Comment: http://ideone.com/eimZyJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> With the C++11 unique_ptr, an object's lifespan can be extended
>   outside of its usual scope

No, it can't.

> The character c, which would usually be released at the end of the
>   scope, survives until the end of the program.

No it doesn't, it survives until the end of the scope, just as normal.

> The second output is 'Y', showing that the unique_ptr does not simply
>   copy its value.

You're right, `unique_ptr` does not copy the value it points to.  But your output here is irrelevant, because your code has undefined behavior when you dereference that pointer, because the thing it points to no longer exists.  The code has undefined behavior again when the `unique_ptr` is destroyed, and calls `delete` on that location (although you can provide a no-op deleter).

> Is it recommended to extend the lifespan of a variable in an way? Is it safe...

Clearly no and no.

> or does it carry the same dangers as a reference?

Yes, this is similar to returning a reference to a local variable from a function.  It's even more similar to having a dangling pointer and dereferencing it, with the addition that `delete` is called on the location for an extra dose of undefined behavior.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly, the `unique_ptr` is still pointing at the address of what used to be a variable. Since its template type is a `char`, it reads the data in that position (whether it be overwritten or not) as a character and outputs that. Upon deletion, the `unique_ptr` will try to delete the data in that position like it would a character, potentially corrupting other resources now allocated to that space.

Comment: @watarok: That is an accurate description of what probably happens most of the time on most implementations.  Just remember that "undefined behavior" means just that.  The behavior is not defined, *anything* may happen, as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: Actually, I'd expect something else on real implementations: no write to `c`, as its single correct use (argument to `cout <<`) can be directly replaced. (Debug builds obviously excepted)